# html5 checkbox returns "on" value instead of what i set it to

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, submit

i got an issue with html5 checkboxes, i have to post it's value on a submit button.
On every click on the check button, i have an onclick that sets its value to "0" if unchecked or to "1" if checked.
The problem is that it works perfectly to uncheck the button and returns the value 0, but when i click it to set it to 1 it then passes "on" as value instead of "1".
Any idea on a roundabout for this?

Here is the code as the button starts unchecked:

```
<input id="dati[3]" name="dati[3]" type="checkbox" onclick="
var x3=document.getElementById("dati[3]").value; 

if (x3=="1") {
    document.getElementById("dati[3]").value="0";
} else {
    document.getElementById("dati[3]").value="1";
}
">
```

If the button starts checked it has the same problem, it unchecks correctly, but values "on" instead of "1" when clicked again to check it

Comment: Add value attribute in the input element
`<input id="dati[3]" name="dati[3]" value="0" type="checkbox" onclick="ff()">`

Comment: Added value ='1', and cahnged " and ', but still doesn't work... : <input id="dati[3]" name="dati[3]" type="checkbox" checked value="1" onclick="var x3=document.getElementById('dati[3]').value; if (x3=='1') {document.getElementById('dati[3]').value='0';} else {document.getElementById('dati[3]').value='1';}">

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this way:

```
<input id="dati[3]" type="hidden" name="dati[3]" value="1">
<input id="IarITK0MIY" type="checkbox" checked value="1" 
onclick="var x3=document.getElementById('dati[3]').value;
if (x3=='1')
{document.getElementById('dati[3]').value='0';
} else {document.getElementById('dati[3]').value='1';}">
```

now it works as supposed in my code, i can send "dati[3]" with 1 or 0 depending on the value of check box checked or not.

thank you to everybody for help!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
    <input id="dati[3]" name="dati[3]" type="checkbox" onclick="
var x3=document.getElementById("dati[3]").value; 

if (x3=="1") {
    document.getElementById("dati[3]").value="0";
} else {
    document.getElementById("dati[3]").value="1";
}
">
```

This is completly wrong syntax. i dont even know why your browser is executing any of the code
You cant use `"` within the code. u have to use `'` in the javascript code
Like this:

```
 <input id="dati[3]" name="dati[3]" type="checkbox" value="0" onclick="
var x3=document.getElementById('dati[3]').value; 

if (x3=='1') {
    document.getElementById('dati[3]').value='0';
} else {
    document.getElementById('dati[3]').value='1';
}
">
```

Maybe this even causes your error. try it and tell me if it fixed it

Comment: changed this way: <input id="dati[3]" name="dati[3]" type="checkbox" checked value="1" onclick="var x3=document.getElementById('dati[3]').value; if (x3=='1') {document.getElementById('dati[3]').value='0';} else {document.getElementById('dati[3]').value='1';}"> but still don't work...

Answer (score 0):

If a checkbox isn't checked then it won't be a successful control. That means it won't be submitted at all, not that the submitted value will be `0`.

If it is checked, then it will submit its value. You haven't got a `value` attribute so its default value will be `on`.

You have JavaScript to try to change its value, but that will never run because your HTML has syntax errors in it. The first `"` inside the JavaScript will end the attribute value. This leaves you with this:

```
onclick="var x3=document.getElementById("
```

which will throw a JavaScript error.

Forget about trying to submit `0` or `1`. Move the logic server side and care about if the field is submitted or not instead of the specific value it has. You could include `value="1"` as an HTML attribute so it will submit either nothing or `1` instead of nothing or `on`.

A more usual approach would be to use `name="dati[]" value="3"` and worry about which values were in the array instead of the positions they were in.

Comment: thank you for your debug. I changed " and ', but still doesn't work, i understand what you say about checkbox submit nothing if  not checked, this is why i am trying to change this behaviour. Unfortunately i cannot put this logic to the server side, because this is code generated by code. So i really need a way to get 0 or 1 from the checked/unchecked button from client side, because i have to forward this value with a submit. now the code is as follows <input id="dati[3]" name="dati[3]" type="checkbox" checked value="1" onclick="var ... etc ..."> but still doesn't work